# How can write "takes 2 integers, returns a Point_t representing these integers" function in C programming?

Tags: c, function, structure

```
typedef struct { int x; int y; } Point_t;
Point_t construct_point(int x, int y); /* takes 2 integers, 
                                          returns a Point_t representing 
                                          these integers */
```

How can write this function?

Comment: I don't understand what can do. I beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is really straightforward:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point_t;

Point_t f(int x, int y)
{
    Point_t p = { x, y };

    return p;
}
```

And (to beat possible comments upfront): no, this is not returning a reference to a local variable.